# Django rest framework Router - how to add customized URL and view functions

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django Rest Framework's Default Router and try to customize my links.

How do I set arrange something like as the following:

1. `/myModels/dosomething` (*and get it listed in API Root view*)
2. `/myModels/addModel?name=abc&address=xyz`

   **Views.py**

   ```
   class MyModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
       queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
       serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
   ```

   **urls.py**

   ```
   router = routers.DefaultRouter(trailing_slash=True)
   router.register(r'mymodels', views.MyModelViewSet)
   ```

Answer (score 12):

Let me show how to use `ViewSet` and `router`:

According to [defaultrouter](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#defaultrouter), your viewset needs to declare the views in the class.

I give an example about user api and guide you as the following:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    """Userviewset
    Restful Structure:
        | URL style      | HTTP Method | URL Nanme   | Action Function |
        |----------------|-------------|-------------|-----------------|
        | /users         | GET, POST   | user-list   | user_list       |
        | /users/<email> | GET, DELETE | user-detail | user_detail     |
    """
    # Router class variables
    lookup_field = 'email'
    lookup_value_regex = '[\w.%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}'

    # Viewsets class variables
    #queryset = User.objects.all()

    def list(self, request):
        """GET - Show all users"""
        print request.version
        api_result = user_list.lists_all_users()
        return Response(api_result)

    def create(self, request):
        """POST - Add new user"""
        api_result = user_list.create_new_user(request.data)
        return Response(api_result)

    def retrieve(self, request, email=None):
        """GET - Show <email> user"""
        api_result = user_detail.retrieve_the_user(email)
        return Response(api_result)

    def partial_update(self, request, email=None):
        return Response()

    def destroy(self, request, email=None):
        """DETELE - Delete <email> user"""
        api_result = user_detail.destroy_the_user(email)
        return Response(api_result)
```

When I finish the UserViewSet  containing basic restful api, I register in `router`:

```
router = routers.SimpleRouter(trailing_slash=False)
router.register(prefix=r'users', viewset=UserViewSet, base_name='user')
```

So there will generate with corresponding urls:

- `list`and `create` are with corresponding url: `/users`
- `retrieve`, `partial_update` and `destroy` are with corresponding url: `/users/<email>`

Suppose you need to add more customize urls, you should use `list_route` or `detail_route` to expand the viewset:

```
@list_route(methods=['post'])
def login(self, request):
    """POST - login by user"""
    ...
```

So the new action is with corresponding url:

- `login`is with corresponding url: `/users/login`

I hope it can help you.

Comment: Could you clarify what your user_detail and user_list objects refer to?

Comment: @list_route(methods=['post']) OUTDATED!!

Answer (score 10):

You can add more endpoints to a default router by using `@detail_route` or `@list_route` decorators on views.

`@list_route` will create a new endpoint on `/myModel/new-route/`, whereas `@detail_route` will create new endpoint on `/myModel/<id-of-model>/new-route/`

However if you want to completely replace the endpoints provided by Default router, you should think about writing a custom router.

[DRF's documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#custom-routers) has good explanation of custom router as well as a sample custom router as example is [there](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#custom-routers).

Comment: This was deprecated in DRF 3.8: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/3.8-announcement/#deprecations. You can use an @action decorator instead.